# How to Set Media Volume Control for Android Adobe AIR?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript, air, adobe

In General, JAVA based android app development. we may use...

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

So that activity makes volume controller to control MEDIA Volume. 
If I want to achieve this in Adobe Air based android app. 
How do I do that?

Comment: I want to know how to do this as well!

Answer (score 3):

How about building an AIR native extension to interact with the system volume for Android.

Like:  https://github.com/nweber/SystemVolumeNativeExtension

Related Explanation article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Expected behaviour from the github readme

> When changing the volume using the hardware volume keys the system
>   volume popup will be displayed.  The AIR application will be notified
>   of the new volume after the system volume popup disappears.  This
>   means that the user can press the hardware volume buttons several
>   times before AIR is notified of a volume change. When changing the
>   volume from AIR the system volume is changed, but the system volume
>   popup is not displayed.

Comment: Is there no way to do in AIR? I dont think this ANE will be accepted by Apple since its not 64bit and to rebuild it need a mac which i dont own currently.